# Collection was modified where items are not being modified

Tags: c#

I am developing a simple game with the XNA library for C#. In the following code snippet I am getting the

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

error at the top of the second foreach loop. In my (relatively limited) experience of C# this occurs when attempting to modify the underlying collection during a loop. However, as far as I can see I am not modifying the enemy_positions collection in any way. All the collections in this code are of the type `List<Vector2>`.

What is happening here?

```
//defines collision behaviour when enemy is hit
int be_no = 0;
List<Vector2> tmp_bullets = bullet_i_position;
List<Vector2> tmp_enemy = enemy_positions;

foreach (Vector2 bullet in bullet_i_position)
{
    //get bullet collision box
    Rectangle bullet_col = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(bullet.X - 12), Convert.ToInt32(bullet.Y - 12), 25, 26);

    int en_no = 0;

    foreach (Vector2 enemy in enemy_positions)
    {
        //get enemy collsion box
        en_box = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(enemy.X), Convert.ToInt32(enemy.Y), 75, 75);

        if (temp_r.Intersects(en_box))
        {
            //remove all colliding elements
            tmp_enemy.RemoveAt(en_no);
            tmp_bullets.RemoveAt(be_no);
            bullet_direction.RemoveAt(be_no);

        }
        en_no++;
    }
    be_no++;
}

//update actual lists
bullet_i_position = tmp_bullets;
enemy_positions = tmp_enemy;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lines:

```
List<Vector2> tmp_bullets = bullet_i_position;
List<Vector2> tmp_enemy = enemy_positions;
```

are not cloning the list, they're just creating a local reference to the same list. The direct solution would be to change these two lines to:

```
List<Vector2> tmp_bullets = new List<Vector2>(bullet_i_position);
List<Vector2> tmp_enemy = new List<Vector2>(enemy_positions);
```

But this will be allocating a new list every time the method is called, which is going to be terrible for garbage collection (especially in a game), so the better solution is to remove your foreach loops and replace them with reverse for loops. This works because you only get that exception when iterating a collection with enumerators. The same problem does not apply to regular for loops. For example:

```
for (int i = bullet_i_position.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Vector2 bullet = bullet_i_position[i];

    // ...
}
```

Also the reason for the **reverse** iteration is that removing an element while regularly iterating means that you'll skip the element after a removed element (beause the indexes shift down by 1)

Comment: Thanks for the immediate solution. Also the extra detail about looping makes a lot of sense, so I will be changing how I do that in the future (I come from a PHP background where I don't have to think about the type of loop much).

Comment: Yeah, the only time you need to do that is when removing elements, since most managed languages don't like it when you remove an element from an enumerator/iterator while enumerating. Other than that, `foreach` loops work all the time.

Comment: Another solution I use is to use `ToArray` instead of creating a new list.

Comment: @ashes999: ToArray still allocates a new object.  It's a little more efficient than making a new List, but only very very slightly.  Avoiding the creation of any new object is much better.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch that's news to me. Arrays also convey that meaning of "read-only collection." Is there a better way to do this? I'm adding and removing when I see this exception.

Comment: @ashes999 Any way you create a second collection that doesn't modify the first has to allocate another set of memory on the heap. No way around that.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Vector2> tmp_enemy = enemy_positions;
```

Does not make a copy of enemy_positions and assign it to tmp_enemy. Instead, tmp_enemy points to  enemy_positions. Thus, any change in tmp_enemy is reflected in enemy_positions.
If you want to make an actual copy, this is a better approach:

```
List<Vector2> tmp_enemy = new List<Vector2>(enemy_positions);
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have mentioned you have encountered the difference between reference and value types

i would suggest you replace the foreach loops with something similar to the below

```
for(int i = 0; i<bullet_i_position.count;i++)
  {
     bool hascollided = false;
     for(int j = 0; j<enemy_positions.count;j++)
        {
          if(collisionOccurs)
               {
                hasCollided = true;
                enemy_positions.RemoveAt(j);
                j--;
               }
       }
   if(hasCollided)
      {
         bullet_i_position.RemoveAt(i);
         i--;
      }
}
```

you need to consider what would happen if the bullet collided with 2 enemies at the same time in the above example it would take out both

Comment: The reverse iteration process suggested by Robert Rouhani is much more elegant; changing the value of the iterator inside a for loop is generally considered to be bad practice, and calls for refactoring.

Comment: that is very true although you still need to be careful you do not remove the object too early